# Adobe Air Application - back from background black screen

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an adobe air application, for both android and iOS, with the latest air sdk and all, flash CS6. I have implemented the following code, to pause the game whenever the user puts the application in the background using the following method :

```
naApplication = NativeApplication.nativeApplication;  
naApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, eActivate);
naApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, eDeactivate);
naApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, eExiting);
```

And then :

```
private function eActivate(e: Event):void
        {
            // app has opened or resumed 
            trace("state eActivate");
            naApplication.removeEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, eActivate);
            naApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
        }

private function eDeactivate(e: Event):void
        {
            // app is going to be moved to background 
            // --- Pause Game Code ---
           //

            naApplication.removeEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, eDeactivate);

            naApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
        }

private function eExiting(e: Event):void
        {
            trace("state eExiting");
            // app is going to be closed by user or by the OS (usually to free up memory)
            // do whatever exit code here then remove all listeners (to be clean don't rely on OS to close them) 
            naApplication.removeEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, eActivate);
            naApplication.removeEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, eDeactivate);
            naApplication.removeEventListener(Event.EXITING, eExiting);
            naApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
            // removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eMainTimer);
        }
```

This code is working perfectly on iOs, with no bugs, but the problem is actually on Android. Whenever the user puts the app in the background, and comes back to it, first he will be greeted by a black screen, he has to touch anywhere to remove the black screen, and see the resume screen. 
So the problem is : 
- The android user puts the app in the background
- It pauses correctly 
- Whenever he comes back to the game, a black screen appears with nothing else, if he touches anywhere on the screen , the black will go away and the resume screen will appear.
How can i remove this black screen!?

EDIT :

Whenever the user goes into background , the app automatically calls the pause functions and pause the game, if i do use the StageQuality low and high principle,it will bypass all my code whenever the app goes to forground

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515570/air-for-android-black-screen-after-device-alarm?rq=1

Comment: not quite well.. nothing really changed, same situation..any ideas?

Comment: This is a classical bug that exist for years but still nobody knows for sure what is causing it. What helped for me once was to set the Stage quality to stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW; on deactivate and then stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH; on activate - this forces the stage to redraw stuff. Are you using video or camera in your app ? I remember there was some black screen issues regarding that as well but don't remember exactly what it was

Comment: @Philarmon could you please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I basically added

```
if ( stage ) stage.quality = stage.quality
```

in the onActivate handler.

Works here.